# Error con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Tengo esta conexión:

```
<?php
   # Conexion con la Base de Datos
   $userdb = 'administrador';
   $passworddb = '1234567';
   $dbhost= 'dbserver';
   $dbname = 'sk_modular';
?>
```

Y estoy llamando a la base de datos para que me traiga unos datos:

```
require("conexion.php");
require("error.php");
$link= mysqli_connect($dbhost,$userdb,$passworddb,$dbname);

 if ($link->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
    } 
  mysql_select_db($link) or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
  $query= "SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-148' UNION SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-160'";
  $result = mysql_query($query)
            or die("Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL");
            mysql_close();
  echo '<option value="0">Escoger altura</option>';
  while (($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) {
    echo '<option value="'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'">'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'</option>';
  }
  //liberar resultador
  mysql_free_result($result);
  //Cerrar la conexión
  mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Al entrar a la URL me sale este error:

> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
> given in D:\Modular\php\DB.php on line 13 No se pudo seleccionar la
> base de datos

No se qué me falta en:

```
mysql_select_db()
```

Comment: **No confundir al usar mysql con mysqli** , en la conexión usas una y para ejecutar otra , verificar que todas sean iguales tanto `mysqli_connect` , `mysqli_query` , `mysqli_fech_array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posibles errores en su código

- **`El uso de diferentes Extensiones`** para manipular la Conexión [(mysqli)](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) y para ejecutar la misma  [(mysql)](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysql.php)
- No hace falta Seleccionar la base de datos , si ya se paso anteriormente como parámetro a la función [mysqli_connect](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php)

**`Dejar de Usar la extensión Mysql por problemas de seguridad y además está obsoleta.`**

El código final sería así :

```
require("conexion.php");
require("error.php");
$link= mysqli_connect($dbhost,$userdb,$passworddb,$dbname);

 if ($link->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
    } 
  $query= "SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-148' UNION SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-160'";
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
  echo '<option value="0">Escoger altura</option>';
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'">'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'</option>';
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me resolvió el error.

Answer (score 3):

Hola el error que te esta dando, es por que solo estas pasando la conexión al método ***mysqli_select_db***; y  te falta la base de datos ***mysqli_select_db(conexión,"bdname");***. Ahora si estas usando ***mysqli*** no necesitas llamar al método ***mysqli_select_db*** ya que el ***mysqli_connect*** estas pasando la base de datos, te dejo el ejemplo de una función que puedes usar para realizar tu conexión a la base de datos Ej:

```
define("SERVER", "dbserver");
define("USERNAME", "administrador");
define("PASSWD", "1234567");
define("DATABASE", "sk_modular");    

public static function conexion(){
        include_once "config.php";
        $conexion = new mysqli(constant('SERVER'),constant('USERNAME'),constant('PASSWD'),constant('DATABASE'))or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        $conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        return $conexion;
    }
```

Llamamos la conexión y ejecutamos el query:

```
$db = classDb::conexion();    

$query= "SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-148' UNION SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-160'";
      $result = $db->query($query)
      echo '<option value="0">Escoger altura</option>';
      while (($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) {
        echo '<option value="'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'">'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'</option>';
      }

      //Cerrar la conexión
      mysqli_close($db);
```

> Nota: si estas usando ***mysqli*** no lo puedes combinar con **mysql** y es algo que estoy viendo en tu código.

Answer (score 2):

```
require("conexion.php");
require("error.php");
$link= mysqli_connect($dbhost,$userdb,$passworddb,$dbname);

 if ($link->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
    } 
   $query= "SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-148' UNION SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-160'";
  $result = mysql_query($query)
            or die("Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL");
            mysql_close();
  echo '<option value="0">Escoger altura</option>';
  while (($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) {
    echo '<option value="'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'">'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'</option>';
  }

  //liberar resultador
  mysql_free_result($result);
  //Cerrar la conexión
  mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Supongo que deberias borrar el `mysql_select_db()`, puesto en el $link ya estas pasando la base de datos para conectarte.

Comment: le borro `mysql_select_db()` y me sale lo siguiente `
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: [2002] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión. (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in D:\Modular\php\DB.php on line 15`  No se por que me pone localhost

Comment: @EduardZora Revisa la respuesta de yoel. aunque ese error 2002 es por acceso denegado, tal vez la contraseña o el host este mal puesto